# max-width doesn't work with float

Tags: css-float, responsive-design, css

I'm trying to design a responsive page. I have 2 divs with the same height.
They both have the max-width property and the max-width is working. Once I add the float:left property the max-width doesn't affect them.

Here's an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEEW5/2/)

```
<div class="color1">
   Some Text
</div>
<div class="color2">
    Bla
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
```

and the CSS:

```
div{
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.color1{
    background-color: #6AC1FF;
    max-width: 400px;
}
.color2{
    background-color: #BDBCF4;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

I want them to be align vertically. Is there another way to make it other than float and
keep the max-width?

Comment: `display: box;` isn't valid. Did you mean block or inline-block?

Comment: Have you tried to clear them after? Add a class with the property `clear: both;` and then make a div using that class right after the two boxes.

Comment: display: inline, or display: inline-block.

Comment: *Updated my code and already tried inline, inline-block. not working...

Comment: Elements that are floated will shrink to the width of their content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use defined width percentages and float: http://jsfiddle.net/dEEW5/3/

```
div{
    height: 100px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.color1{
    background-color: #6AC1FF;
    width: 80%;
    max-width:400px;
}
.color2{
    background-color: #BDBCF4;
    width: 20%;
    max-width:100px;
}
```

Use defined width percentages with inline-block: http://jsfiddle.net/dEEW5/4/

```
body{font-size:0}
div{
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
}
.color1{
    background-color: #6AC1FF;
    width: 80%;
    max-width:400px;
}
.color2{
    background-color: #BDBCF4;
    width:20%;
    max-width:100px;
}
```

Inline-block where the 2nd block drops when it can no longer fit within the container instead of shrinking: http://jsfiddle.net/dEEW5/5/

```
body{font-size:0}
div{
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
}
.color1{
    background-color: #6AC1FF;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:400px;
}
.color2{
    background-color: #BDBCF4;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I started using flex and I thought it might be a good answer to my own question.
I've added a container with `display: flex` and set each div a `flex-grow`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dEEW5/182/)

### HTML

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="color1">
      Some Text
  </div>
  <div class="color2">
      Bla
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div{
    height: 100px;
}
.cont{
     display: flex;
}
.color1{
    background-color: #6AC1FF;
    flex-grow: 4;
    max-width: 400px;
}
.color2{
    background-color: #BDBCF4;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `max-width: 400px` is gone allow the div to expand to that, you should combine it with `min-width: (value);`

Answer (score 0):

When floated your divs don't have a specified width; thus they default to the width of the content (hence not being 400px/100px wide).

Answer (score 0):

Use a specific width in px for your largest view and then set "max-width: 100%".

e.g.

```
 div{
    height: 100px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.color1{
    background-color: #6AC1FF;
    width: 400px;
    max-width:100%;
}
.color2{
    background-color: #BDBCF4;
    width: 100px;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

For my site I was happy with both divs displaying at 100% once the screen size was too small to display them side by side. But if you want another step in the responsiveness you could add in an extra @media query to choose an inbetween step before they go to 100% width.